Add line break between yaml values
I'm creating a custom yaml using the yaml function. Since the yaml can become large I would like to insert some line breaks between values. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do that. Here is some reproducible code:
library(yaml)
your_yaml <- list(test = list(TRUE,
                              FALSE),
                  test2 = list(A = TRUE))

yaml_text <- as.yaml(your_yaml)

cat(as.character(yaml_text), sep = "\n", append = TRUE)
#> test:
#> - yes
#> - no
#> test2:
#>   A: yes

This creates a really simple yaml, but now I would like to insert a line break between - no and test2 values. If we use a "\n" this doesn't work:
library(yaml)
your_yaml <- list(test = list(TRUE,
                              FALSE),
                  "\n",
                  test2 = list(A = TRUE))

yaml_text <- as.yaml(your_yaml)

cat(as.character(yaml_text), sep = "\n", append = TRUE)
#> test:
#> - yes
#> - no
#> '': |2+
#> 
#> test2:
#>   A: yes

Created on 2024-06-07 with reprex v2.1.0
My expected outcome should look like this:
#> test:
#> - yes
#> - no
#> 
#> test2:
#>   A: yes

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to enter a line break like this in a custom yaml?

Here is a potential workaround using empty key:
library(yaml)
your_yaml <- list(test = list(TRUE,
                              FALSE),
                  "",
                  test2 = list(A = TRUE))

yaml_text <- as.yaml(your_yaml)
cat(as.character(yaml_text), sep = "\n", append = TRUE)

yaml_text_br <- gsub("'': ''", "", yaml_text, fixed = TRUE)
cat(as.character(yaml_text_br), sep = "\n", append = TRUE)

That gives:
test:
- yes
- no

test2:
  A: yes

